# Drag and Drop in Java - Painting more than just a border

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable, jlist

I have a JTable and a JList and I have my code set up so that I can drag from the JTable to the JList using built in Swing methods.

When I drag from the JTable to the JList, the "image" that is dragged is simply a border of the thing I am dragging. Specifically, in the case of the source being a JTable, the image is just a border of the row I selected to drag.

How can I override what this "image" is? How can I get it so that the user can drag text, not just a border (rectangle)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check out

- http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/05/my-drag-image-is-better-than-yours.html
- http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/08/drop-target-navigation-or-you-drag.html
- http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/04/smooth-jlist-drop-target-animation.html
- http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/07/drag-images-for-everyoneand-we-do-mean.html

Now some may not be quite what you after, but he's done so much with drag n drop, it'd be waste note to check out as much as you can

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to take advantage of [*Drop Location Rendering*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/droplocation.html) to achieve the desired effect. If you are already doing so, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits any problems you encounter. This [example](http://forums.devshed.com/java-help-9/custom-drop-location-rendering-665843.html) may be helpful.